# Windows service (file copy) run with administrator account but access deny to path

Tags: vb.net, exception, windows-services, unauthorized

I have developed a windows service with vb.net that watch an specific folder and when a file rename event occur, copy the file to another folder. The service was setup on Microsoft Windows 2012 [Version 6.3.9600].
Here is the core code

```
Private Sub DoWhenFileRenamed(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal evnt As RenamedEventArgs)
    .
    .
    .
    FileName = evnt.FullPath.Substring(Len(x) + 1)
    TmpPath = "c:\tmp\"+random name+"\"
    Directory.CreateDirectory(TmpPath)
    File.Copy(evnt.FullPath, TmpPath + FileName, True)
    .
    .
    .
```

The service run with administrator privilege but when i rename the file a System.UnauthorizedAccessException raise with this message:

```
Access to the path <evnt.FullPath> is denied
```

thanks for your help